# MS Word macro -- special handling for top of page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write an MS Word macro to drop down one line and type a certain phrase unless the cursor at the very top of the document or following a "hard" page break, in which case it should only type the message.  The code goes pretty much like this --

```
If <TOP OF PAGE> Then
  Selection.TypeText Text:="top of page"  
Else
  Selection.TypeParagraph
  Selection.TypeText Text:="not top of page"  
End If
```

-- but I don't know the specific syntax for testing whether the cursor is at the top of a page.  Can anyone fill me in?  My software version is MS Word 2003.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) = 1`.

```
If Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) = 1 Then
  Selection.TypeText Text:="top of page"  
Else
  Selection.TypeParagraph
  Selection.TypeText Text:="not top of page"  
End If
```

`Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)` will return the line number of the current selection within that page. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213848(v=office.12).aspx).

PS: I have tested this with Word 2010 and I don't have access to previous version. So, give it a try.

Comment: That's very close in that it works as desired on every line except the first -- it returns "top of page" at every character position on the first line, whereas that should only happen before the occurrence of the first character.  But if I combine combine that with wdFirstCharacterColumnNumber (which I got from the link you provided), it works.  Much obliged,